# index sort accented letters after normal letters (after "Z")! How to put them in a more logical position?

Tags: indexing, accents, sorting, makeindex

index sort accented letters after normal letters (after "Z")! Is there a way to put them in a more logical position?
For example "àncora" is put after "Zorro", instead of in the "a" section.
I don't like it.

Comment: The usual approach is to provide a sort argument.  For the example you give, that would be `\index{ancora@àncora}`.

Comment: @Barbara This is great but I have used a \newcommand for highlighting a word and put it on the index, and I'm not sure it works this way.  My \newcommand is \newcommand {\voce}[1]
{{\color{BrickRed}\emph{#1}}\index{#1}}

Comment: You will need a dedicated command for the collation: `\newcommand{\voced}[2] {{\color{BrickRed}\emph{#1}}\index{#2}}`. Alternatively, using `expl3` code, you can split at any `@` and then feed a `\voced`-type command its two parameters in all cases. @egreg is pretty handy at expl3 and already has some token-splitting-related answers on this site. Unrelated: to ping somebody who is not the OP, I think the full user name without spaces must be used: e.g., @barbarabeeton.

Comment: Depending on how your command `\voce` is used, my first reaction would be to define a second command, perhaps `\Voce`, with three arguments, the added one being the sort value.  Without more specific information in the question, preferably a small compilable example. too much guesswork is involved to be able to devise a usable answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks, all your comments are useful and smart. Solved

Comment: @Cicada -- Your use of the full form of my user name resulted in a successful ping.  Thanks.  (Without that, I would have been unaware of the relevant comment.)